# We need to find the limit of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

We need to find the limit of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)z^n$

for what values of $z$ does the series converges?

for convergence we need $\limsup|(n+1)z^n|^{1\over n}<1$
i.e $|z|<{1\over (n+1)^{1\over n}}$

Thank you for help.

Comment: The limit of $(n+1)^{1/n}$ is $1$, so the radius is $1$. For the value, differentiate $\sum z^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Your series is the derivative of $\sum_{n\ge 0}z^n$; do you know a closed form for that series?

Your last statement isn’t quite correct: it should say that $$|x|<\limsup_n\frac1{(n+1)^{1/n}}\;.$$